# Creating new modes for CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

I want to highlight only keywords that look like this: `{KEYWORD}`
(basically UPPERCASE words wrapped between single `{}` parentheses)

I tried this by copying the code from the [Mustache Overlay demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html), and by replacing the double brackets with single ones:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode('mymode', function(config, parserConfig) {
  var mymodeOverlay = {
    token: function(stream, state) {
      if (stream.match("{")) {
        while ((ch = stream.next()) != null)
          if (ch == "}" && stream.next() == "}") break;
        return 'mymode';
      }
      while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match("{", false)) {}
      return null;
    }
  };
  return CodeMirror.overlayParser(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.backdrop || "text/html"), mymodeOverlay);
});
```

but it doesn't work very good :)

Any ideas?

Comment: In what ways doesn't it work?

Comment: well it highlights everything from the `{` to the end of the line (and it's not case sensitive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is special handling in the Mustache example because it needs to handle 2-character delimiters (e.g. there are two characters in `'{{'` and `'}}'`). I've never used CodeMirror before, so this is just a guess, but try something like this:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("mymode", function(config, parserConfig) {
  var mymodeOverlay = {
    token: function(stream, state) {
      if (stream.match("{")) {
        while ((ch = stream.next()) != null)
          if (ch == "}") break;
        return "mymode";
      }
      while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match("{", false)) {}
      return null;
    }
  };
  return CodeMirror.overlayParser(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.backdrop || "text/html"), mymodeOverlay);
});
```

---

#### Edit

> it works (though it highlights words with lowercase letters too)

This *should* work:

```
token: function(stream, state) {
  if (stream.match("{")) {
    while ((ch = stream.next()) != null && ch === ch.toUpperCase())
      if (ch == "}") break;
    return "mymode";
  }
  while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match("{", false)) {}
  return null;
}
```

Comment: it works (though it highlights words with lowercase letters too). thank you :p

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the part about only matching uppercase words. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer highlight every chars in brackets.

[image]

My version, if someone else encounter same issue.

[image]

```js
CodeMirror.defineMode('mymode', function (config, parserConfig) {
    return {
        /**
         * @param {CodeMirror.StringStream} stream
         */
        token: function (stream) {
            // check for {
            if (stream.match('{')) {
                // trying to find }

                // if not a char
                if (!stream.eatWhile(/[\w]/)) {
                    return null;
                }

                if (stream.match('}')) {
                    return 'mymode';
                }
            }

            while (stream.next() && !stream.match('{', false)) {}

            return null;
        }
    };
});
```