# CodeMirror Twitter like highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, codemirror

I'm using Twitter API to scheldule Tweets. The App have a Create Template module, I would like to accomplish something like this using CodeMirror:
[image: Twitter]

My actual mode definer looks like:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode('text/twitter-like', function() {
    return {
        token: function( word, state ){
            if ( word.match(/^_\w+/) ) {
                return "blue-text";
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

This is making a infinite loop every time I type something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364854/creating-new-modes-for-codemirror look it up

Comment: did @analog-nico answer worked for you or do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CodeMirror Manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi) states:

> It should read one token from the stream it is given as an argument, optionally update its state, and return a style string, or null for tokens that do not have to be styled.

Did you try to return `null` instead of `false`?